# Wamp server connection

Tags: php, android

I have developed an android app that connect mysql database using php. when making https request to scripts php from other computers located on the same local network no problem, but when trying to request the same scripts from my android phone it gives tcp errors.

Comment: i have also done all the configurations in httpd.conf and i have opened the port 80.

Answer (score 0):

There is however a far better solution. You can access your host machine with the IP address "10.0.2.2".

This has been designed in this way by the Android team. So your webserver can perfectly run at localhost and from your Android app you can access it via `http://10.0.2.2:8080`.

Comment: My objective is to make an android app that read/write data from and to mysql database via local network (Wirless). Our system consist of clients from pc and android devices.

Comment: You can do this by simply implementing this example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? If it's a forbidden error then it could be your httpd config file blocking your android. Can you tell from the error whether the problem is in your android application or a network connectivity error?

Comment: It gives the following message when i use chrome on my mobile device:Network Error(tcp_error) A communication error occurred "Operation timed out"...

Comment: If you're getting a timed out error then it's a networking issue. Is your android in the same network as your server? There might be a firewall blocking it.